# Gravar arquivos via upload na pasta configurada com o nome estipulado

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Estou em ambiente de desenvolvimento, e gostaria de gravar uma imagem colocando-a após o upload em uma pasta que configurei localmente em minha máquina assim:

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = '../static/media/'

O problema são dois:

1º A imagem não vai para a pasta que criei e dei permissão de gravação

2º O nome do arquivo, eu gostaria que contivesse o id da instância "instance.id". Quando submento formulário, o campo na tabela recebe um nome assim: "2019-07-25_085029.207286.None.Roupeiro.jpeg" onde a data e hora estão como eu gostaria, sendo que, somente o id junto ao nome serviria para não termos problema de sobrepor o arquivo na pasta, para fins de informação posso deixar com a data, o que esta errado é o Nome.

```py
models.py

from django.db import models
from qnow_user.models import User
from django.conf import settings
from datetime import datetime,date
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

User = get_user_model()

def user_directory_path(instance, filename):
    return "%s.%s.%s" %(datetime.now(), instance.id, filename)

#Mobile type descripton
class MobilieType(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=False,unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.description

class Quotation(models.Model):
    #Quotation number
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

    #Quotation owner
    client = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=User, related_name='quotation')    

    #Quotation cration date
    date_create = models.DateField(default=date.today)

    #Quotation update date
    date_update = models.DateField(default=date.today)

    #House type for quotation
    HOUSETYPECHOICES = (
    ('Apartamento', 'Apartamento'),
    ('Casa', 'Casa'),
    ('Comercial', 'Comercial'),
    ('Escritório', 'Escritório'),
    ('Outro', 'Outro'),
    )
    house_type = models.CharField('Tipo de imóvel para cotação?',max_length=20,
        choices=HOUSETYPECHOICES,blank=False,default='Casa',
        help_text='Nos informe o tipo do seu imóvel(Apartamento, casa...)')

    STATUSCHOICES = (
        (0,'Pendente'),   #Client requested quotation
        (1,'Em Análise'), #Company analizing quotation
        (2,'Liberado'),   #Quotation released for provider
        (3,'Orçado'),     #Quotation provider
    )
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUSCHOICES, blank=False,default=0)

    #House set to quotation                
    house_set = models.CharField(max_length=100,default='Digite aqui!')

    #Mobile type 
    mobile_type = models.ForeignKey(MobilieType,on_delete=True,related_name='MobileType')

    #Mobile description to others  
    mobile_description = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=False,default='Encontrei na lista acima!')

    #Mobile of particulars
    particulars  = models.TextField(blank=False)

    image_photo = models.FileField(upload_to=user_directory_path)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Cotação'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Cotações'

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.client)


views.py

from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.shortcuts import get_list_or_404, get_object_or_404
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from .models import Quotation
from .forms import QuotationForm

@login_required
def quotation_client(request):
    template_name = '../templates/client_quotation.html'
    form = QuotationForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            Quotation = form.save(commit=False)
            Quotation.client = request.user
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save(commit=True)
                return redirect('qnow_site:site')
            else:
                form = QuotationForm()
        else:
            context = {
                'origin':'client',
                'active_page_client_provider':'active'
            }
            return redirect('qnow_user:login_client_start')
    else:
        form = QuotationForm()
    context = {
                'active_page_client_provider' : 'active',
                'form':form
                }
    return render(request,template_name,context)
```

Answer (score 0):

#### 1. A imagem não vai para a pasta que criei e dei permissão de gravação

Na documentação do [`settings.MEDIA_ROOT`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#media-root) fala:

> Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.

Ou seja, é especificado que o caminho deve ser absoluto e você está usando um caminho relativo na sua configuração.

Você pode usar a variável `BASE_DIR` definida no início do `settings.py` como ponto de início, usar [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) e [`os.path.abspath`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.path.html#os.path.abspath) para pegar o caminho absoluto da pasta. Ex.:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../static'))
```

---

#### 2. ID é None ao nomear arquivo

Se você olhar a documentação do [`FileField.upload_to`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to) verá que na parte onde explica o argumento `instance` tem o parágrafo:

> In most cases, this object will not have been saved to the database yet, so if it uses the default AutoField, it might not yet have a value for its primary key field.

Tradução livre:

> Na maioria dos casos, o objeto ainda não foi salvo no banco de dados, então se o Model usa o AutoField padrão, pode ainda não ter valor definido para a chave primária.

Ou seja, quando a sua função é executada o model ainda não foi salvo no banco de dados, por isso `id` é `None`.

Comment: Sobre o MEDIA_ROOT, irei corrigir e vamos ver o que vai dá. Agora sobre o ID, tens razão, entendi isto analisando o código. Ok mas como eu faço para ter um valor único no nome da imagem para garantir que não sobreponha uma imagem enviada?

Comment: Você poderia salvar o model sem a imagem e inserir depois, dessa maneira já teria o ID. Você poderia também usar algum tipo de contador e separar as imagens por pastas, etc... Aí vai depender de como você vai querer fazer.